# objective-c - argument of parent function passed into child block is not changed inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to ios and objective-c programming and currently I'm a bit confused with this behavior -

I have function which calls handler with block inside. This function receives different arguments but inside block handler it's not changed, it stays as it was declared on first call:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
   // called with different strings - "foo", "bar"
   [self startSearchText:searchBar.text];
}

- (void)startSearchText:(NSString *)text 
{
  __block CGFloat page = 1;
  __weak LSAllFavoritesViewController *weakSelf = self;

   // initial search request
  [weakSelf makeSearchWithText:text byPage:page success:^{
    page += 1;
   }];

  // infinite scrolling
  [weakSelf.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^
   {
    // text will remain "foo" for all next requests
    [weakSelf makeSearchWithText:text byPage:page success:^{
         page += 1;
         [weakSelf.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];
    }];
  }];
}
```

Comment: Unsure about your `text` issue, but you don't need to use weakSelf except within the blocks.   Regarding `text`-- you see the issue logging/debugging, or just in apparent behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/blob/master/SVPullToRefresh/UIScrollView+SVInfiniteScrolling.m), it is obvious that `addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:` does nothing except the first time it got called. You should store `text` into a private variable instead, so you can always get latest value from inside the block.

Comment: I ended up with using text as @property of controller

Comment: Yes, that would do too.